# Qt Creator Debugger Log Window unnecessarily escapes many characters makes output distracting

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, qt-creator

Qt Creator Debugger Log Window(Window > Views > Debugger Log) unnecessarily escapes many characters and makes output distracting, how can we fix it?

 
Please see the screenshot.
In the right pane: \n \t and \\ , I don't want them.

[image: Qt Debugger Log Window Screenshot]

Comment: Would something like `printf "%s\n", (char *)0x7fffe036bd33` do what you want?

Comment: It is not about printing just strings it is about any output coming from gdb, for example, see bt command's output above.